# get struct data by name (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, struct

Is there an easy way to get the data out of a struct by searching for his name?

I'm thinking of a struct like this:

```
test = struct('A', ...
[struct('Name','Adam','Data',[1 2 3]) ...
struct('Name','Eva','Data',[11 12 13])]);
```

Now I want to access the Data field by searching for 'Adam' or 'Eva'.

something like this:

```
getStructDataByName(test,'Adam')
```

Does someone know a script or has an idea doing this with not too much effort?

**Edit:**

This is my current solution:

```
function getDataByName(struct,fieldname)

    names = getAllDataNames(struct);

    thisIdx = strcmp(names,fieldname);
    % or
    % thisIdx = ismember(names,fieldname);

    struct.A(thisIdx).Data

end


function names = getAllDataNames(struct)

    for idx = 1:length(struct.A)
        names(idx,:) = {struct.A(idx).Name};
    end

end
```

Should I use strcmp() or ismember()?

Comment: Are you able to use a cell matrix instead? Because then you could just use `ismember`

Comment: @Dan No, I dont think so. I dont build the strucs by myself, it's a given dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.A(strcmp({test.A.Name}, 'Eva')).Data
```

Basically if you call `test.A.Name` it will return a comma separated list of all the names. So by putting `{}` around that we concatenate all those into a cell matrix. We can then use `strcmp` to find the indices that match the name you're after. Note that if your names can be repeated then this will return a comma separated list over all so you might want to put the curly braces around the entire expression in that case.

Comment: btw I see you used `strcmp` in your attempt, that will also work here if you prefer it to `ismember` (no `find` required though because logical indexing takes care of that for you)

Comment: where is the difference between find() and ismember()?

Comment: I put a tic/toc in my code and found out, ismember() takes a lot longer than strcmp().

Comment: Thanks @Phab, I'll change it in the answer too then.